# top logo alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to align my logo at the top but failed to do so

http://pligg.marsgibson.info

I am trying to change the following in my style.css but failed

```
#logo {
padding: 40px;
margin-left :-40px;
```

see the screenshot I want to align the same

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/jhxaph.jpg]

my style.css

[pligg.marsgibson.info/templates/wistie/css/style.css](http://pligg.marsgibson.info/templates/wistie/css/style.css)

Comment: Post your [relevant CSS and HTML](http://sscce.org) here; ideally post a demo to reproduce your problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.cm/) or similar. That way we can see what's going on, and work out where the problem is.

Comment: If you want the gaps above and bellow "a few millimeters only", then why are you setting the padding to 40px?

Comment: Everyone uses a different size display/resolution... so the concept of moving something _"a few millimeters"_ is practically meaningless.   This is why we use percentages and/or pixels.

Comment: Sparky672 thanks for pointing the content tag
I didnt notice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#content` tag has a `padding` of `10px`, is the logo within the content tag? If so, that explains the space.

Comment: Yes thank u for pointing this content tag